# Puppeteer - webScraper

Tags: puppeteer

I have trouble replace hyperlinks with regular text on a website that I scraped by Puppeteer.
I'm able to get the HTML file, but when it renders, the stylesheet doesn't work, the hyperlinks lead to errors.
Anybody can help me with this, please?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs')

const scrapeWikipedia = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
    // defaultViewport: null
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  const wikiUrl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groundhog_Day_(film)'
  await page.goto(wikiUrl, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

//replace hyperlink 
  await page.evaluate(_ => {
    document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="javascript"]')
      .forEach(a => {
        a.href = '#'
      })
  });
 //get html file get from the website with
  const html = await page.content();

  fs.writeFileSync("./outputHTML/index.html", html); 
 await browser.close();

}

scrapeWikipedia()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Sure, you downloaded the HTML file but you haven't downloaded all of the assets from wikipedia. Any links that are relative are going to break. If the site says, say, `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">`, well, that file is not on your computer or localhost unless you put it there so naturally the request will fail. Usually when you "scrape" a site, you take a few pieces of data you're interested in. Downloading an entire page is another matter. What is your goal exactly?

Comment: @ggorlen my goal is to get the article and then save it into  Cloud firestore ->  user can get it to read later in offline mode. So I don't want them to click on hyperlinks, because it will lead to an error.

Comment: Do you just want the article plain text? Please show the first relevant chunk of result you want from the groundhog day link.